# WebGL - Plotting approximately 60 million points on a map, in real time

Tags: performance, dictionary, webgl, openlayers, points

I haven't started learning WebGL yet, but I would like to know its capabilities first.

When I downloaded and modified the following WebGL example:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_particles.html

At 10 million it was fine, at 50 million it just won't load.

With changes, would WebGL support that amount of data points rendered onto a map?
Thanks!

Comment: No. 10 million points should be enough for anybody.

Comment: Who can see that many points and make any sense of it ? Maybe some points are more important than others and should get priority.

Comment: Well the idea is to create a dot map, a map generated by population and without shape files.

Answer (score 1):

try splitting your 50 million BufferGeometry object into 50 one million BufferGeometry objects

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't even fit 50 million points in the v8 heap in JavaScript. To handle something like this you would need to do some sort of streaming or preprocessing.